# getBSSID() returns "02:00:00:00:00:00" and getNetworkId() returns "-1" even with the "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" permission set

Tags: android, networking, permissions, android-wifi, bssid

I just noticed that WifiManager.WifiInfo.**getBSSID()** now returns **02:00:00:00:00:00** and that WifiManager.WifiInfo.**getNetworkId()** returns **-1** even with the **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION** permission set.

It's interesting because it used to work great before. It seems that the problem appeared after an Android update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to replace **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION** with **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION**.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, make sure that the Location service is turned on as well. I only had WiFi enabled and that is not enough.